# SAP HANA SQL: STDEV

Tags: hana, stdev

In SQL Server there is a function **STDEV**.

Apparently it is **not available in SAP HANA** SPS 12

Error message:

```
SAP DBTech JDBC: [277]: not a GROUP BY expression: The function STDEV is not supported aggregate function or ...
```

**How to fix / work-around this?**

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `STDDEV`

(with two D)